# Apache Cordova `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` function always return error 5 (ENCODING_ERR)

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I'm around this issue for some days and no results. I want to have a function that returns the size of a file, but `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` returns error 5 (`ENCODING_ERR`)

```js
function getFileSize (fileUri, callback) {
  var fileSize = null
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileUri, function (fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function (fileObj) {
      fileSize = fileObj.size
      callback(fileSize)
    },
    function (err) {
      console.error('fileEntry error:\n', JSON.stringify(err))
      callback(fileSize, Error(err))
    })
  },
  function (err) {
    console.error('resolveLocalFileSystemURL error:\n', JSON.stringify(err))
    callback(fileSize, Error(err))
  })
}
```

I'm using as input something like `fileUri = 'file:///storage/9C33-6BBD/DCIM/Camera/20190616_183142.jpg'`

Any idea what the problem might be?
Any nice simple plugin to get the file size?

### specs

I'm using Cordova v `9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)`. My plugins are these:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera-with-exif" spec="~1.2.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~2.4.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" spec="~0.8.15" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^3.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-pdf-generator" spec="^2.0.3" />
<plugin name="info.protonet.imageresizer" spec="https://github.com/protonet/cordova-plugin-image-resizer.git" />
<engine name="android" spec="^6.2.0" />
```

Comment: I could see an open issue in cordova file plugin - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/issues/289 similar to the one you mentioned above. Did you had a look? its still open though

Comment: @Gandhi yes, I had already looked upon it and it didn't help. I wanted to open an issue in Github there, but they say that for help we should use SO. Support for Apache Cordova is really a burden.

Comment: if this issue is with latest version of file plugin, then you can try out with old version to see if it works and can also check if its happening with specific version of android